# Function to get position of substring, using backreferences in Neo4j Cypher regex

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using the web interface and Neo4j Community 2.1.3.

Is there a Cypher function or combination of functions that gives the position of a substring in a string or uses its location as a starting point for a SET clause, similar to FIND or SEARCH in Google Spreadsheets or substring-before() and substring-after() in XPATH? Something like:

```
MATCH (p)
WHERE p.name=~"^.*?\\, .*?$"
SET p.lastName=LEFT(p.name,FIND(p.name,", ")), p.firstName=RIGHT(p.name,FIND(p.name,",")+1)
RETURN p ;
```

The FIND() function would return the position of the substring (in this case: a comma plus single space), so the LEFT and RIGHT functions can be used to extract a partial string. Something like the XPATH substring-before() and substring-after() accomplish the same thing in one function. The Cypher string functions SUBSTRING, LEFT, RIGHT are only of limited use without this additional functionality — unless I'm just missing something.

Along these lines (string manipulation), is there a way to use backreferences to Cypher regex WHERE matches? We can use groups for matching, but I can't figure out how to reuse those groups using \1 or $1 in a SET clause. The above code could be made simpler using regex groups and some kind of backreferences:

```
MATCH (p)
WHERE p.name=~"^(.*?)\\, (.*?)$"
SET p.lastName=\1, p.firstName=\2
RETURN p ;
```

Are these things possible yet? I can't find documentation or examples. I've seen the [Regx4Neo plugin](https://github.com/mszargar/Regx4Neo), but the command shell is beyond my abilities at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your example is so contrived that this is irrelevant, my apologies, but you could just split on ", " and then `SET` properties equal to the different elements resulting from the split. So, with the following example data:

```
CREATE (:Person {name:'White, Nicole'}),
       (:Person {name:'Bastani, Kenny'}),
       (:Person {name:'Hunger, Michael'})
```

We can get first and last names and set them as properties:

```
MATCH (p:Person)
WITH p, SPLIT(p.name, ", ") AS names
SET p.firstName = names[1],
    p.lastName = names[0]
```

Result:

```
MATCH (p:Person)
RETURN p.firstName, p.lastName

p.firstName   p.lastName
Nicole        White
Kenny         Bastani
Michael       Hunger
```

Comment: Yes, my example was oversimplified — I'm not trying to solve that specific problem with the fixed string ", ". Putting the results of a SPLIT function in an array would work fine to allocate the resulting strings, but I would really need to be able to process the input to the SPLIT function with regex. It's the same as I mentioned with the SUBSTRING, LEFT, and RIGHT functions: they're of only limited if they require exact strings and pre-established positions as input. To me it's a general need for working with strings, not just one instance I'm trying to solve.

Comment: The real question is how would you use regex for the input to Cypher string functions, including SPLIT? Say you had a database of burial sites of Chinese leaders, with captioned images in the format "Wang Jian (847 – July 11, 918) is buried Chengdu." How would you remove the parenthetical dates from the captions, and leave the rest? That's a straightforward regex + backreference solution in other languages. How is abitrary string manipulation like this meant to be handled in Cypher?

Comment: Perhaps that's something that should be done in the pre-processing in your client-language?

Comment: For your concrete problem, probably split on "(" and ")" and join back the remaining parts?

Comment: Michael indicates the answer I needed: no pattern matching or back-references in Cypher functions. My examples were unfortunate: both contained literals. Elsewhere, I'm able to do more and easily with regex. Since regex is already supported in WHERE clauses, why not extend it to functions? It would be a powerful feature. I'm using just the Neo4j web interface. It's silly to export data back out of Neo4j to process it, then re-import it to do testing or restructuring. One of the strengths of Neo4j is supposed to be the ability restructure data without that kind of RDBMs allergry to change!